# How to remove the gap inside bootstrap input element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this input-group,as you can see there's unnecessary gap inside input field and I want to get rid of it

[image]

As you can see above,this black line is the distance between my number and link button.How can I remove it?

```css
.resetToDef{
  display: block;
  width:25.8%;
  max-width: 195.1px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #FF7921;
}


 .resetToDef a{
  font-size:12px;
  color:#FF7921;
  border: none;
  text-decoration-line: underline
}

.resetToDef input{
 display:inline-block;
 width:57px;
 border:none;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <div class="resetToDef input-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="30">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="float-right btn">Back to default</a>
                 </div>
```

Comment: `.resetToDef input{flex:none;}`

Comment: @mrben522 didnt work

Comment: it works in your snippet, what's different in your real environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your snippet :

[image][image]

The width is automatically calculated by flex. So if you remove flex, you can then play with the width and the padding.

```css
.resetToDef.input-group > input.form-control {
    flex: none;
    width: 52px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Resulting in :

[image]

Beware that the little arrows may not look exactly the same size from browser to browser.